# Properly Save/Import Geocoded Data in Python

Tags: python, geocoding

I have a list of addresses that I geocode in python. I'm using the free Nominatim geocoder so the geocoding step takes 1 second per address. I want to save the geocoded data so I don't have to repeat the geocoding step each time I run my program. I then want to calculate distances using that data. My problem is that when I save the data to csv and read it back in the distance function no longer recognizes it as latitude longitude location. How do I save it correctly or read it in so that it will be recognized as a latitude and longitude location?

The example code below runs without the line `df = pd.read_csv('Data/Location/Final/RCs_AddressGeo.csv')`, but when the line is included it raises an Error :

> "ValueError: Failed to create Point instance from string: unknown
>   format."

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.distance import geodesic as dist

df = pd.read_excel('Data/Location/Final/RCs_Address.xlsx')
locator = Nominatim(user_agent='myGeocoder')
geocode = RateLimiter(locator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)
df['geo'] = df['address'].apply(geocode)
df['point'] = df['geo'].apply(lambda x: (x.latitude, x.longitude))
df.to_csv('Data/Location/Final/RCs_AddressGeo.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('Data/Location/Final/RCs_AddressGeo.csv')
v = df['point'][0]
d1 = df['point'].apply(lambda x: dist(x, v).miles)
```

Comment: Not my area of expertise but would geopandas be able to handle this data more effectively?

Comment: Maybe so, but I was looking for an answer that allowed me to save as csv. I've got something that works below, but any explanation for why would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with the following code. It works, but I don't understand why the list(zip()) command does the trick. If someone could explain, it would be helpful.

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.distance import geodesic as dist

df = pd.read_excel('Data/Location/Final/RCs_Address.xlsx')
locator = Nominatim(user_agent='myGeocoder')
geocode = RateLimiter(locator.geocode, min_delay_seconds=1)
df['geo'] = df['address'].apply(geocode)
df['latitude'] = df['geo'].apply(lambda x: x.latitude)
df['longitude'] = df['geo'].apply(lambda x: x.longitude)
df.to_csv('Data/Location/Final/RCs_AddressGeo.csv')

df = pd.read_csv('Data/Location/Final/RCs_AddressGeo.csv')
df['point'] = list(zip(df['latitude'], df['longitude']))
v = df['point'][0]
d1 = df['point'].apply(lambda x: dist(x, v).miles)
```